Tensorflow custom layer accessing value of output tensor from previous layer
So I'd like to create a custom Tensorflow.Keras layer with purpose of returning label name as a text.
The previous layer is an argmax that returns integer representing the index of predicted class and I want to pass it as input to the next layer which returns the real name of the class as the final output of the model.
This is my custom layer
class LabelLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, labels, dtype='int16'):
    super(LabelLayer, self).__init__()
    self.labels = labels

  def call(self, inputs):
    return self.labels[inputs]

And this is how I build the model, on top of an existing model
new_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  model,
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast( tf.argmax(x[0]), dtype='int16'), name='predicted_label'),
  LabelLayer(class_labels) # TODO
])


Right now it throws an error:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor"

I tried to using some suggested solutions such as tf.slice or invoking .numpy() method but it doesn't seem to work.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a more correct way to achieve what I want?

Hi Dudede ,The error you are facing shows that the input to the labelLayer is still in tensors but you cannot directly index a list. you can use tf.gather  because it allows you to collect values from the labels tensor. It works on a tensor not in the list .Try this your model will work correctly.
